# How to use jar file in java program from command promt?

Tags: java, jar

I am using following structure

```
package-a/package-b/ab
```

created jar of above class.

I want to use it in following program

```
import package-a.package-b.ab;


'public class hello1'
'{'
' public  static void main(String args[])'


'{'


'ab aa=new ab();'



 'aa.helloworld();'


'}'


'}'
```

I am using following command

```
'Making jar - jar cf sample2.jar ab.class'
'jar created successfully'
```

but when i am using 
`java hello1.java`
but  getting error Classnot found error?

Comment: clean the extranuous single quotes, keep the formating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use    `java -jar sample2.jar` to run the jar

Comment: Thank you ...........Another question - I am accessing a jar file in which a java class without main method ...can i use that jar file to print simple message with another function

Comment: You need a main class..... And you need to specify that in the Manifest.MF as Main-Class: com.mypackage.Hello

Comment: @sandy_ws how the jvm start the execution of any class/jar without main method.You need to add the main method